# MySQL: Unable to connect using TCP/IP over SSH

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We have an EC2 and RDS instance on Amazon Web Services. I usually first connect to the server using Putty and then access the database through a tunnel from my localhost.

I am now trying to directly connect to the database using TCP/IP over SSH, but get the following error. I am able to connect other applications such as FileZilla directly without creating any tunnels, but not able to connect MySQL. Please advise. There is no entry in known_hosts file.

**Error:**

```
[Window Title]
MySQL Workbench

[Main Instruction]
Failed to Connect to MySQL at database.aws-server.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 through SSH tunnel at username@100.100.100.100:22 with user username

[Content]
Cannot open SSH Tunnel: Error connecting SSH tunnel: The host 100.100.100.100 fingerprints mismatch.
Expected key: hjd83iuwe98jdoiw8euoqeuo83eqe308
Server sent: 8ru84ru8ur984u8djc0938y4jddj398e
Please verify if it's correct.
To continue, delete entries for the host from the C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\ssh\known_hosts file.

[OK]
```

Comment: There *must* be an entry in the known_hosts file... otherwise, where is the "expected key" value coming from?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot somehow your comment opened my eyes to notice the known_hosts file, which I promptly deleted to get my connection working. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

I am connected to my rds database using the following script-

**ssh -L 3406:database.aws-server.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 -i  username@100.100.100.100**

this command will create a tunnel on your local machine port 3406 of the mysql's default port 3306.

after that you can connect at 3406 port in your application

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, I am able to connect using a tunnel, but now I need to make a third party cloud app connect directly without tunnel. Hence, I need to test and get TCP/IP over SSH method working.

Answer (score 0):

ssh-keygen -f "C:\Users<USER>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\ssh\known_hosts" -R "database.aws-server.rds.amazonaws.com"